# regression analysis (by year and firm)

Tags: r, repeat, linear-regression, finance

Sorry, I'm awkward in English and R. 
Hope you understand my words.

my data set as follows.

```
year, week,       A017670,   A030200,  A032640,   Market,  IND.20

2000, 2000-01,       0.02,    -0.001,    0.005,    0.007,   0.004,

2000, 2000-02

...

2000, 2000-52

2001, 2001-01

...

2014, 2014-52
```

I want to extract Adjusted `R-squared` and `SSE` from my `regression models`.

and I want write (save) Adjusted `R-squared` with `SSE`.

My models are follows:

```
lm(A017670~MARKET+IND.20, subset=(year=2000)) 

lm(A017670~MARKET+IND.20, subset=(year=2001)) 

... 

lm(A017670~MARKET+IND.20, subset=(year=2014)) 


lm(A030200~MARKET+IND.20, subset=(year=2000)) 

lm(A030200~MARKET+IND.20, subset=(year=2001)) 

...

lm(A030200~MARKET+IND.20, subset=(year=2014)) 


lm(A032640~MARKET+IND.20, subset=(year=2000)) 

lm(A032640~MARKET+IND.20, subset=(year=2001)) 

...

lm(A032640~MARKET+IND.20, subset=(year=2014))
```

I need adjusted `R-squared` and `SSE` each model.

My data is 15 years data of 700 companies`(A017670, A030200, A032640, ...........)`

So, I have to run 10,500 times the regression.

It is very boring.

Also, `IND.20` means the industrial yield.
Industrial Average is 30 `branches.(IND20, IND21, IND22, .............IND49)`

Thank you.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "can be processed at a time"....

Answer (score 0):

Create combinations of companies and years:

```
models <- setNames(
  expand.grid(
    names(df1)[grep("^A",names(df1))], 
    unique(df1$year), stringsAsFactors = F), 
  c("company", "year"))
```

Call `lm` on every combination:

```
do.call( rbind, 
  lapply( seq_len(nrow(models)), FUN = function(i) {
    formula1 <- sprintf("%s ~ MARKET + IND.20", models$company[i])
    fit1 <- lm( formula = formula1, data = df1[ df1$year == models$year[i], ]  )
    sfit <- summary(fit1)
    data.frame( 
      year = models$year[i],
      company = models$company[i],
      AdjRSq = sfit$adj.r.squared, 
      SSE = deviance(fit1) )
  })
)
```